# HazelCast - How to call a business service through HazelCast Client

Tags: hazelcast

I am using HazelCast to cache data from a database in a Proof Of Concept to a likely customer.
Client layer is in C#. I am using the .Net dll to retrieve data from the HazelCast layer.

My requirement is to execute some business logic steps followed by a transaction. This transaction will insert/update few records in the database.
So, I want to execute a service method which will take an object as input and return another object as output. The method implementation will have the business logic followed by the transaction. The method should return the result of the execution.

I see that I cannot invoke a generic service through the HazelCast client.
Client only provides methods to get data through HazelCast datastructures.
Is there a solution for my requirement?
Thanks for your answers.

s.r.guruprasad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Distributed Executor Service` or `Entry Processor` is what you are looking for but apparently it is not made available for a .NET client.
Solution would be have another webservices layer which can make use of Hazelcast's Java client which supports them.

http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.5/manual/html/distributedcomputing.html

Comment: Thanks for confirming my understanding.

Comment: For reference, here's a newer version of the docs :) http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.7/manual/html-single/index.html#distributed-computing